# Why IntelliJ generates Maven ATTACHED_JAR xml files?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

My project has dependency from ActionBarSherlock, HoloEverywhere and others that are added like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
    <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

And for some reason IntelliJ generates files like that:

```
.idea/libraries/Maven__ATTACHED_JAR__com_actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4_3_0.xml
```

With contents:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Maven: ATTACHED-JAR: com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:apklib:4.3.0">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

I would add these files to source control, but they keep changing. Every now and then additional line is added in that file:

```
<root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/target/actionbarsherlock-4.3.0.jar!/" />
```

Is there anythig I could do to get rid of these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are part of IntelliJ's internal configuration, "getting rid of them" would break your IDE.

IMO it's rare you'd want to check in your IDE configuration files, particularly if there's more than one developer. Add the directory to your SCCS's ignore list.

Comment: but then why that repeating line is added from time to time?